# Retain JMS message even if node crashes

Tags: jboss, jms, jbpm, hornetq

In our application, we have a JMS HornetQ, and JBPM is consuming the messages.HornetQ and JBPM are running in same server group. We have marked the queue as Persistent. What if the message is picked up by JBPM and then the node crashes. Now, the message is lost. Is there any way to handle this and remove the JMS message only after JBPM finishes processing?

Answer (score 0):

Need to have a transaction manager that automatically rolls back, not sure if HornetQ supports that but most MQ providers do and I assume it has something.  Without transaction, once the message is picked off, it's gone no matter what.